# Launch Chrome without hardware acceleration (OS X)

Tags: macos, google-chrome

For reference (and screenshot): https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/60700949?hl=en

OS X 10.11, Macbook Air 2015. I just updated Chrome from a slightly earlier 84.x.x.x to 84.0.4147.89. Upon launching the app now, I get a completely blank gray window without even a URL bar. The death-wheel spins and then it crashes. I've never seen a legitimate app behave this way in 30 years.

Launching from terminal I see this:

`[0723/152018.747279:WARNING:process_memory_mac.cc(93)] mach_vm_read(0x7fff54e1d000, 0x2000): (os/kern) invalid address (1)`

`[2084:34307:0723/152018.992135:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(439)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.`

From what I've read, the flags `--no-gpu` and/or `--disable-gpu` are no longer valid in the latest "stable" release. Here are the flags I've thrown at it so far:

`/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --use-gl=swiftshader --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer --no-sandbox --no-xshm --no-gpu --disable-accelerated-compositing --disable-gpu-compositing`

Does anyone know if there's a config file I could modify or *some way* of getting it to launch without hardware acceleration? Not truly a coding question but it's driving me nuts. Filed this on the Chrome Help site and got no responses.

Comment: It appears to work for me...

Comment: Link is broken. Maybe you need a login?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to open `chrome://settings/?search=hardware` in your browser and then turn off `Use hardware acceleration when available`.

Comment: That might work if I could get Chrome to open. I'm asking whether there is a way to disable hardware acceleration *prior to opening Chrome*.

Comment: According to https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/ and https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/master/content/public/common/content_switches.cc#146, "--disable-gpu" is still valid.

"the flags --no-gpu and/or --disable-gpu are no longer valid": where did you read that?

Comment: I can't find the exact link but it was mentioned in the chrome forum by other mac users who have experienced this problem. It is still listed among the chromium flags. In any case it does not solve the problem.